# Why does Finder interact so slowly with NAS?

Tags: macos, finder, nas, afp

I have a **Synology NAS D213+**.

When I want to connect the NAS to my Mac, Finder mounts a new volume which behaves like a normal partition.

But it interacts so slowly - I click on a folder, and it takes a huge number of seconds till it's open. Explorer on Windows is much faster when it comes to network interaction.

What can I do? Change the protocol? It must be AFP, so do I have to change the protocol elsewhere in the kernel?

Comment: I have this same NAS and have noticed FINDER is slow but using ForkLift seems much faster to browse folders and files.

Comment: I'm using a DS411j running DSM4.1. Like you, it's noticeably slower with Mountain Lion (though it wasn't exactly blazing fast with Lion).

I suspected it had to do with versions support in ML, so what I did was to run tmidiagnose and reported the results back to Apple.

Comment: You should be able to export the file system as SMB and mount it that way on the Mac.  This often has better performance than with non-apple implementations of AFP

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to use NFS. You should also try to manually mount the partition from the terminal, so you can add some options too, like

```
  -nolock,locallocks,rdirplus
```

This made my browsing much faster, even over wifi.

Cheers